# How to use Path::Class::Rule for two string - Perl

Tags: perl

I am using `Path::Class::Rule` for getting absolute path of required file . 
As my file name either have  `UILogs[_d]*` or `log.main` format. Below is the code which i am using

**Code :**

```
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    eval { require Path::Class::Rule }
        or system("ppm install Path::Class::Rule");
}

use Path::Class;
use Path::Class::Rule;
use Cwd qw();
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy;

my $root = "logpath";

my @uiLogDirs = grep { -d $_ && !/A\.\.?\z/ } dir($root)->children();

my $iter = Path::Class::Rule->new->file->name(qr/ UILogs[_d]* | log.main/)->iter(@uiLogDirs);
while ( my $uifilepath = $iter->() ) {
    print "$uifilepath\n";
}
```

But above code is not working i.e unable to search the file. It is working fine if i am using

`my $iter = Path::Class::Rule->new->file->name(qr/log.main/)->iter(@uiLogDirs);`

**Logs file Example**:

1. `Monkey_SDCard_UILogs_141008_154230`
2. `log.main`

Can anyone help me out in the above issue?

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are significant in regular expressions unless you use the `/x` modifier:

```
qr/UILogs[_d]*|log\.main/
qr/ UILogs[_d]* | log\.main /x
```

BTW, I'm not sure about the first alternative. Do you really have filenames like `UILogs___d_`?

Comment: It is still not working i can give you the both logs example 1. Monkey_SDCard_UILogs_141008_154230 2. log.main